# I cannot save an image using Julia REPL

Tags: image, julia

I am trying to create and save an image using Images library but nothing happens.

```
using Images

function create(n::Int64)
    img = zeros(3,n,n)
    for i in 1:n
        for j in 1:n
            img[:,i,j] = i*j*rand(3)
        end
    end
    return img
end

save("img.png", colorview(RGB, create(300)))
```

I have tried ImageView library but it shows a grayscale image instead of an RGB one.

Comment: Could you precise wich version of julia and wich version of Images you are using? I have some differences with my versions.

Comment: Julia v1.2.0 and Images v0.21.1.

Answer (score 1):

Your `save` should have worked, but it also presumably showed a warning:

```
julia> save("/tmp/test.png", img)
┌ Warning: Mapping to the storage type failed; perhaps your data had out-of-range values?
│ Try `map(clamp01nan, img)` to clamp values to a valid range.
└ @ ImageMagick ~/.julia/packages/ImageMagick/0EUaI/src/ImageMagick.jl:171
```

That's because your intensities are out-of-gamut: JuliaImages uses a 0-to-1 scale for the components of RGB images. This is the result I got:

[image: result]

If you look very carefully you can see a few colored pixels, but the rest white. That's because any value >=1 is interpreted as saturated.

See the JuliaImages documentation: https://juliaimages.org/stable/quickstart/#The-0-to-1-intensity-scale-1 and https://juliaimages.org/stable/arrays_colors/#fixedpoint-1